# Как исправить "кривизну" предложения?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*...не оставлял затею создать более совершенную работу, чем ему казалась имеющаяся.*

Вижу, что криво, а как переделать — не знаю.

Comment: Каков смысл выражения "создать работу"? Это о произведениях искусства? А "имеющаяся работа"? Кто ее имел?

Comment: Каким другим словом можно назвать то, что он хотел создать?

Comment: Где находилась работа, кто ее создал, кто владел? Каким словом можно заменить "имеющуюся"?

Comment: Не берусь сказать с полной уверенностью за автора, но мне кажется, что под "имеющейся" подразумевается состояние этой работы на данный момент. Что-то вроде текущей версии, хоть слово "версия" может быть и неприменимо к данному случаю. Сказал так для понятности.

Comment: Имеется ввиду книга.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможные варианты редактирования:

(1) *Его не оставляло желание создать нечто более совершенное, чем уже выполненная им работа*.

(2) *Его не оставляло желание усовершенствовать выполненную им работу.*

**Примечание**. Слово ***казалась*** здесь лишнее. Если было стремление усовершенствовать работу, значит, она **казалась** ему недостаточно совершенной.

Comment: А я понял это корявое предложение так, что прежняя работа была не так уж плоха, но ему **казалось**, что она несовершенна, и у него появилось почти маниакальное желание создать нечто более совершенное.

Answer (score 2):

Мне приходит в голову только перестроить фразу:

> Имеющаяся работа не очень нравилась ему, и он не оставлял идеи/затеи создать что-то более совершенное.

Answer (score 1):

Мне не нравится в данном контексте как слово *работа*, так и слово *имеющаяся*. Но нет достаточно информации, чтобы понять, чем их заменить. А схема построения предложения может быть такой:

**Он не оставлял затеи создать гобелен более совершенный по сравнению с тем, каким  казался ему висящий перед ним на стене.**

Comment: Наверное, гОбелен.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова. Спасибо, Вы, как всегда, на страже!

Comment: Странный порядок слов "гобелен более совершенный". Мне кажется, что запятая в таком случае нужна после "гобелена"? Не могу понять...

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, запятая меняет акценты: он хотел создать **гобелен**, и чтобы он был более совершенный,  или гобелен **более совершенный**?

Comment: Честно сказать, уже не соображаю, о чём речь (какие два варианта получаются так и так). Ну да ладно. :)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Розенталь: Не обособляются распространенные определения, стоящие после существительного, если последнее само по себе в данном предложении не выражает нужного смысла и нуждается в определении: Чернышевский создал произведение в высшей степени оригинальное и чрезвычайно замечательное (Д. П.);

Comment: Спасибо, М_Г! Значит, неправильно казалось. :)